# Computer doesn't shut down or restart after installing tlp!

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, reboot, tlp

I have installed tlp using the following commands

`sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw` and `sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms` in ubuntu 14.04. But after that , I can't shutdown or restart my pc. Whenever I try to shutdown/restart it hangs in a black screen with a static cursor in the top left corner.
I have to shutdown holding the power button.
I have removed the above softwares using apt-get remove --purge , but the problem still remains. Any help ?

Edit: Here are some logs from my PC the time it was shutting down
http://pastebin.com/anhg0rtz

Edit2: I uninstalled bbswitch-dkms , now the pc goes to blank screen , I then  set nomodeset in /etc/default/grub , now in the login loop . But the shutdown works now ..

Edit3: Well , Finally I was able to work it again. The problem was I think after installing `sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms` somehow bbswitch-dkms got installed. Which in turn broke the nvidia propriety driver. So What worked for me was

- Removing everything installed
- Purging and reinstalling the nvidia driver.

I don't know if not removing tlp , instead just purge and reinstall nvidia driver would work. If someone have knowledge please let me know.

Comment: Well, did you checked on the Ubuntu Forums? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217602 There is a discussion there about the same issue as yours. Some users seem to have found the solution for this. Or the solutions, because there are several of them, but they don't all seem to work for everybody.

Comment: Well yeah , nothing seems to work for me . Should I post dmesg output ?

Comment: Your laptop isn't a Thinkpad. So why did you install tp-smapi-dkms and acpi-call-dkms?

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://linuxpitstop.com/install-tlp-on-ubuntu-15-04-and-centos-7/

Comment: yeah, but the blog author didn't read the [official docs](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation) completely ;-).